# Differentiating between a Compose Inspector and a Read Inspector

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi, add-in

Is there a way to tell if the current inspector window, in Outlook 2007, is a Read window, or a Compose window?

I know we can capture events, and set flags on it, but I dont want to capture New/Reply/Forward events. Is there a way to tell this from the Inspector object? Any property? Any MAPI property?

A pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probally the easiest way is to see if the Inspectors CurrentItem is Sent or not

```
 Outlook.MailItem currentMail = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

        if (currentMail != null)
        {
            if (currentMail.Sent)
            {
                //Read Mode

            }
            else
            { 
                // Compose
            }

        }
```

Comment: Wow. Thats pretty neat. Thanx.